# No data being displayed on my angularfire applicaiton

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

When I've tried to display my data using:

```
<li *ngFor="let course$ of courses$ | async">
  <pre>{{ course$.title }}</pre>
 </li>
```

With angularfire2 I have no data showing. When I console.log(courses$) I see the following object: 
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}

I've followed this guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject  } from     'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  courses$: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.courses$ = db.collection('/courses').valueChanges();
    console.log(this.courses$);
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [AngularFireDatabase, AngularFirestore],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.comonent.html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course$ of courses$ | async">
      <pre>{{ course$.title }}</pre>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you see the HTTP call in Chrome's debugger ? To see if the DB sends any data ?

Comment: If you want to see the items in the console, do `this.courses$ = db.collection('courses').valueChanges().pipe(tap(items => {console.log('items:', items);}));`. Also make sure you haven't misspelled your collection name in the firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue. This is what I did. It occurred to me that these tutorials I was following may have been outdated, so I referred to the official documentation on their Github page: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/2ebc022d6b680b33d4535f903194a94289bd0107/docs/rtdb/lists.md

It's actually `this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges();` not `` this.courses$ = db.collection('/courses').valueChanges();```

And it's also `db: AngularFireDatabase` not `AngularFirestore`